# Angular 4 - using if else in template error

Tags: angular

I am displaying posts with their comments, and for posts with no comments I would like to display a message that there are no comments for that post, so I have tried to set it up like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)" >
      {{ post.Summary }}
      <ul *ngIf="currentPost == post && commentsVisible">
        <li *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message" *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="comment">
            <p>{{ comment.Name }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.TemplateName }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.CreatedByUserName }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.Preview }}</p>
        </li>
        <ng-template #message>No comments for {{ post.Title }}</ng-template>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

I get an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is complaining about this line.

`<li *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message" *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="comment">`

You can't have `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same element.

**This should work:**

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)" >
      {{ post.Summary }}
        <ul *ngIf="currentPost == post && commentsVisible">
          <ng-container *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message">
            <li *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="comment">
                <p>{{ comment.Name }}</p>
                <p>{{ comment.TemplateName }}</p>
                <p>{{ comment.CreatedByUserName }}</p>
                <p>{{ comment.Preview }}</p>
            </li>
         </ng-container>
        <ng-template #message><li>No comments for {{ post.Title }}</li></ng-template>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

**More info about why this error occurs:  (*Joy Clay's comment*)**

> Just to add a little more context - all structural directives (i.e.
>   the ones that begin with a *) compile down to template attributes,
>   which both explains why you can't have multiple, and why the error
>   message is what it is.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#asterisk

Comment: Just to add a little more context - all [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#the-asterisk-prefix) (i.e. the ones that begin with a `*`) compile down to `template` attributes, which both explains why you can't have multiple, and why the error message is what it is.

Comment: @JoeClay, Yes this is true. I will add that. Thank you,

Comment: I have done the same as you did, and the error is gone, but the message is not visible in the template

Comment: @Leff, The whole message is not visible? Or just the interpolated part? For example do you see.. `No comments for`?

Comment: The whole message is not visible, so I can't see anything not even ```No comments for```

Comment: Is it possible to make this into a plunkr?

Comment: That should work unless maybe its not passing the first if condition. Here is a basic example with that layout.. http://plnkr.co/edit/ymEFSDgDatwT7MYqxrUC?p=preview

Comment: yes, the issue was somewhere else, I will post another question and check your answer as the correct one here, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wrapping div, only one ng statement per element.

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)" >
    {{ post.Summary }}
    <ul *ngIf="currentPost == post && commentsVisible">
    <li *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="comment">
        <span *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message">
            <p>{{ comment.Name }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.TemplateName }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.CreatedByUserName }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.Preview }}</p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <ng-template #message>No comments for {{ post.Title }}</ng-template>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this slight change might resolve the issue for you. Let me know. If not maybe a quick plunker would help.

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)" >
      {{ post.Summary }}
      <ul *ngIf="currentPost == post && commentsVisible">
        <li *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="comment">
            <div *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message">
              <p>{{ comment.Name }}</p>
              <p>{{ comment.TemplateName }}</p>
              <p>{{ comment.CreatedByUserName }}</p>
              <p>{{ comment.Preview }}</p>
            </div>
           <ng-template #message>No comments for {{ post.Title }}</ng-template>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```